# CakePHP Force Typing URLs

Tags: url, cakephp, redirect

Ok, so I have a web application that has a page name 'Contact Us'. It's the same like all contact us pages out there. The input fields are: name, school/company, email, message.

So once the user has fill-out all required information and clicked on submit, he/she will be redirected to a new page and this page is just a message saying "Message sent" or "Message sending failed".

Let us say this is the URL when the user clicked on the submit button: localhost/appname/controller/messagesent

In other websites, if you try to type the URL of the page of the message, you shouldn't be able to access it.

So I want the 'messagesent' page to be accessible ONLY when the submit button is clicked. But if for some reason the user try to access the 'messagesent' page by typing it in the URL, he/she will be redirected to index.ctp.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

EDIT:

So here's the partial code of the Contact Us page:

```
if($this->Contact->save($data)) { 
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'websites', 'action' => 'messagesuccessful'));
            } else{
                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'websites', 'action' => 'messagefailed'));
                }
```

And here's the code for messagesuccessful():

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->layout = 'website';
        }else{
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
```

Comment: you want to pass one argument in messagesent if argument is equal to  your value then messagesent action display other redirect to url page

Comment: public function messagesent ($id){
            if (!$id) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Your request is invalid'));
            } if($id!='you value'){  $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Users','action'=>'index'));}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
function contactus()
{
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if($this->Contact->save($data)) { 
            $this->messagesent();
        } else{
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'websites', 'action' => 'messagefailed'));
            }
    }
    else{
        // put the code here if you access the function directly (not posting any data)
    }
}
```

Make it a private function so no one can access it directly.

```
private function messagesent()
{
    $this->render('messagesent', 'website'); 
}
```

it just render your messagesent file with the 'website' layout. Make sure you keep the messagesent.ctp file in website folder under views folder.

Thanks..!

Comment: This answers my question! Thank you!

Comment: ok, now it's not working anymore. It just redirects to the index. It literally skips the if($this->request->is('post'))

Comment: Ok it works, but the initial problem about not being able to access it when typed in the URL still persists.

Comment: When you typed in the url to access messagesent function. it will not be accessible. It gives (private method) error to user. No one will able to access it directly.

Comment: Didn't see that it's a private function. It works! Now I just have to edit the error message shown. Thank you!